# Es mejor asociar un evento dentro o fuera de una funcion?

Tags: javascript

Tengo lo siguiente, estoy haciendo un "to-do app" sencillo para practicar, pero he visto que muchos cuando hacen el evento de click/enter para ingresar la tarea y se crea la tarea, ahi mismo dentro de la funcion donde se crea se gestionan otros eventos como "eliminar tarea", "chequear tarea".

Por ejemplo:

```
    const checkButton = document.createElement('input');
    checkButton.type = 'checkbox';
    checkButton.checked = isCompleted;
    createItemTask.appendChild(checkButton);
    checkButton.addEventListener('change', () => {
        isCompleted = checkButton.checked;
        taskText.classList.toggle('completed', isCompleted);
    });
```

Como ven, ahi se gestiono el evento 'change' que si yo hago click sobre mi input de tipo chequeo, este cambia. Mi pregunta es, por que? por que cambia, si nisiquiera llamo a la funcion de addTask cuando hago click en este input que se creo.
Tengo entendido que los eventos al hacer click es como que superar toda esa jerarquia y logran por cada elemento creado gestionar cada evento, pero esto no implica que se vuelva a recrear toda la lista y de ahi recien haga el cambio del evento 'change'? No es mejor poner este evento fuera de esta funcion?? (sacando el tema de modulizar para mejor claridad, no voy por este lado)

**Las preguntas son, por si no quedo claro:**

**1.- Por que si yo defino una funcion y dentro de esta funcion pongo un evento sin relacion a esta, este evento se ejecuta sin yo llamar a esta funcion para este otro evento? no me queda bien claro lo de la jerarquia.**

**2.- Hacer esto, no esta generando que se ejecute toda la funcion nuevamente?, no se esta creando todo de nuevo pero con el nuevo valor? como funciona exactamente?**

**3.- Es mejor ponerlo fuera en tema de eficiencia? (Sacando del contexto el modulizar separando en funciones para mejor claridad, quiero saber si solo es eficaz o no)**

```
let inputTitleTask = document.querySelector("#id-title-task");
let addTaskButton = document.querySelector("#id-enter-task");
let listTask = document.querySelector("#id-list-task");


function addTask(){
    const newTitle = inputTitleTask.value;
    const createItemTask = document.createElement('li');
    let isCompleted = false;

    // -------------------------
    inputTitleTask.value = '';
    listTask.appendChild(createItemTask);
    // -------------------------
    const checkButton = document.createElement('input');
    checkButton.type = 'checkbox';
    checkButton.checked = isCompleted;
    createItemTask.appendChild(checkButton);
    checkButton.addEventListener('change', () => {
        isCompleted = checkButton.checked;
        taskText.classList.toggle('completed', isCompleted);
    });
    // ------------------------
    const taskText = document.createElement('span');
    taskText.textContent = newTitle;
    createItemTask.appendChild(taskText);
    // -------------------------
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.textContent = 'Eliminar';
    createItemTask.appendChild(deleteButton);
    // -------------------------

    return createItemTask;
}

addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', () => {addTask();} );
inputTitleTask.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => { if( event.key === 'Enter' ){ addTask(); } });
```